# Implicit declaration of function ‘mknod’ but I have the headers included

Tags: c, linux, named-pipes, raspbian, mknod

I am trying to make a C program that uses named pipes to communicate with a C++ program on a Raspberry Pi 3.

The warning that GCC is spitting out when I compile some code of mine:

`/home/pi/BluetoothTest/btooth.c|76|warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mknod’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]|`

Here is the code from  for the function, including the #if above it:

```
#if defined __USE_MISC || defined __USE_BSD || defined __USE_XOPEN_EXTENDED
extern int mknod (const char *__path, __mode_t __mode, __dev_t __dev)
     __THROW __nonnull ((1));
```

and here are the includes that I have in the file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci_lib.h>
#include <bluetooth/rfcomm.h>
//#include <linux/stat.h>
```

The program attempts to create the pipe here:

```
umask(0);
fifo = mknod(PIPE_LOC, S_IFIFO|0666, 0);
fp = fopen(PIPE_LOC, "w");
```

fifo is an `int` that isn't used anywhere else and fp is a `FILE*` to the pipe. Some debugging that I have done shows that `fifo` has a value of `-1` after `mknod` runs, likely because of the compiler not seeming to be able to find the implementation of the function.

How do I make it so that GCC knows where to find the implementation of `mknod`?

Comment: A more portable way to create a named pipe is the `mkfifo` function, which is POSIX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see that for declaration of `mknod()` function to stay after preprocessing stage, one of three macros `(__USE_MISC, __USE_BSD,  __USE_XOPEN_EXTENDED)` should be defined. Otherwise, declaration of mknod() will be removed during preprocessing stage.

```
#if defined __USE_MISC || defined __USE_BSD || defined __USE_XOPEN_EXTENDED
extern int mknod (const char *__path, __mode_t __mode, __dev_t __dev)
 __THROW __nonnull ((1));
```

You can use compiler options: `-std=gnu99 -D_GNU_SOURCE` or you can define these macros on your own and place them above header file inclusion.

Comment: BRAVO! Saved me a truckload of time. I did notice those pre-compiler variable in the headers, but wasn't aware of the one variable to rule them all! -D_GNU_SOURCE. My code was compiling on macOS Sierra but when I built it on RH I was getting that error for popen, getopt, strdup, etc... and your suggestion fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing a definition of some feature test macro required for the respective headers to define `mknod`. According to the Linux Programmer's Manual for the function (`man 2 mknod`) the macros for glibc are:

> ```
> mknod():
>     _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 500
>          || /* Since glibc 2.19: */ _DEFAULT_SOURCE
>          || /* Glibc versions <= 2.19: */ _BSD_SOURCE || _SVID_SOURCE
> ```

Try adding `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500` to your compile flags to see if that helps.